# Beamer vertical navigation bar with horizontal subsection dot

Tags: beamer, themes, navigation, mini-frames

I would like to have an horizontal subsection navigation inside a vertical navigation bar.

The idea is to obtain the same subsection navigation as for the outersmoothbar but in a vertical navigation bar.

I look for it but cannot find any solution. Any idea ?

Elendil

Edit: I'm writing my theme and I put here the peace of code concerning the sidebar.

```
% ============================================================
% LENGTH
% ============================================================
\newlength{\SidebarWidth}
\setlength{\SidebarWidth}{\beamer@sidebarwidth}
\newlength{\HeadlineWidth}
\setlength{\HeadlineWidth}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\HeadlineWidth}{-\SidebarWidth}
\addtolength{\HeadlineWidth}{-1pt}
\newlength{\HeadlineHeight}
\settoheight{\HeadlineHeight}{\large TexTe}
\addtolength{\HeadlineHeight}{1ex}

% ============================================================
% SIDEBAR
% ============================================================
% color
\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=white}

% sidebar itself
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar \beamer@sidebarside}
{
  \vfill
  \insertverticalnavigation{\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
  \vfill
}%

% vertical rule
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas \beamer@sidebarside}{
  \vspace*{-0.7\HeadlineHeight}%
  \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext{%
    \hspace*{0.99\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
    \color{black}\rule{1pt}{0.9\paperheight}%
  }
  \else{%
    \color{black}\rule{1pt}{0.9\paperheight}%
  }
  \fi
}

% section in sidebar
\setbeamertemplate{section in sidebar}%{sidebar theme}
{%
  \vbox{%
    \vskip1ex%
    \beamer@sidebarformat{3pt}{section in sidebar}{
      \centering\tikz[opacity=1.0] \node[xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[height=0.7\beamer@sidebarwidth]{obian/sec\expandafter\insertsectionheadnumber\expandafter}};%
    }%
  }%
}

% section in sidebar shaded
\setbeamertemplate{section in sidebar shaded}%{sidebar theme}
{%
  \vbox{%
    \vskip1ex%
    \beamer@sidebarformat{3pt}{section in sidebar}{
      \centering\tikz[opacity=0.3] \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[height=0.7\beamer@sidebarwidth]{obian/sec\expandafter\insertsectionheadnumber\expandafter}};%
    }%
  }%
}

% Patch sidebar to not hide section when show subsection
\patchcmd{\insertverticalnavigation}%
{\ifx\beamer@nav@css\beamer@hidetext{\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar}}\else{\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar shaded}}\fi}%
{{\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar}}}{}{}
```

And a simple example could be this one loading the previous code in the preamble:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents[subsectionstyle=show]
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item No frametitle
\item section 1
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item No frametitle
\item section 1
\item subsection 1
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which theme are you using? Can you please provide a minimal document showing your current settings?

Comment: I'm writing my theme and code are large. But I add the part of code concerning the sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution by re-writing the internal macro `\insertverticalnavigation`.
I put the code if it can help someone.

If you have any idea to improve, please let me know.

In a MyStyle.sty file I wrote:

```
% Style
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{MyStyle}[2013/06/21 Beamer theme]

% Outer theme
\useoutertheme[left]{sidebar}

% Package
\RequirePackage{wasysym} %\Circle, \CIRCLE -> subsection symbol

% Length
\newlength{\SidebarWidth}
\setlength{\SidebarWidth}{\beamer@sidebarwidth}

% Internal insertverticalnavigation macro
\def\insertverticalnavigation#1{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\SidebarWidth}
    \centering
    \vbox to \paperheight{%
      \def\sectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{%
        \ifnum##5=\c@part%
        \def\insertsectionhead{##2}%
        \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##1}%
        \def\insertpartheadnumber{##5}%
        \vskip0.9em
        \hbox{{%
          \usebeamerfont{section in sidebar}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in sidebar}%
            \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{%
            \ifnum\c@section=##1%
              \ifnum\c@subsection=0\relax%
                {\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar}}%
              \else%
                \ifx\beamer@nav@css\beamer@hidetext%
                  {\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar}}%
                \else%
                  {\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar}}%
                \fi%
              \fi%
            \else
              {\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar shaded}}%
            \fi}}}%
        \vskip0pt
        \beamer@currentsubsection=0\relax\fi}%
      \def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{}%
      \def\beamer@subsectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{%
        \ifnum##1=\c@part%
        \def\insertpartheadnumber{##1}%
        \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##2}%
        \def\insertsubsectionheadnumber{##3}%
        \def\insertsubsectionhead{##5}%
         \beamer@tocifnothide{\ifnum\c@section=##2\ifnum\c@subsection=##3\beamer@nav@css\else\beamer@nav@oss\fi\else\beamer@nav@ooss\fi}%
        {\hskip0pt\hbox{{%
          \usebeamerfont{subsection in sidebar}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subsection in sidebar}%
            \hyperlink{Navigation##4}{%
            \ifnum\c@section=##2%
              \ifnum\c@subsection=##3%
                \ifnum\c@subsubsection=0\relax%
                  {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar}}%
                \else%
                  {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar}}%
                \fi%
              \else%
                {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar shaded}}%
              \fi%
            \else%
              {\usebeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar shaded}}%
            \fi}}}%
        }%
        \fi}%
      \dohead%
    }%
  \end{minipage}
}

% subsection in sidebar
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar}
{
  \usebeamercolor{subsection in sidebar}\CIRCLE%
}

% subsection in sidebar shaded
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in sidebar shaded}
{
  \usebeamercolor{subsection in sidebar shaded}\Circle%
}
```

And a MWE could be:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{MyStyle}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item No frametitle
\item section 1
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 1}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item No frametitle
\item section 1
\item subsection 1
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 2}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item No frametitle
\item section 1
\item subsection 2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item No frametitle
\item section 2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This little example provide me what I want which is subsection in horizontal mode inside a vertical navigation bar.